# Android Timer which works on both background and foreground

Tags: android, timer, android-service, wakelock, background-service

I'm now working on an app which will track students' studying time.
The student can press start button and start studying.
And stop when he finish studying.

When screen is on or phone is plugged in,the text view and progress bar is updating every second .(I means it works fine)
But when the screen is off,updating the textview and progress is stopped after 10 seconds of sleeping the phone.
I think it may be the activity is pausing.
Is that right?

I tested by using:

1. partial wakelock
2. service

Both of these ways make the battery drains.
Is there any idea for this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got an answer.
I read the time when at onPause().
And stop updating view.

At the time of working onResume().
I again read the time.
Then I update the view by adding (onResumeTime-onPauseTime) then resume updating.

So,now I don't need to use service.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Service class, it will work in background when activity will be puased

[enter link description here](http://blog.danielnadeau.io/2013/10/android-services-tutorial-run-tasks-in.html)
[enter link description here](http://blog.danielnadeau.io/2013/10/android-services-tutorial-run-tasks-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Alarm Manager**
If you have a service or an activity in your application which should perform a repetitive task you cannot reply on a TimerTask or similar approaches and control it from your Android component. Activities and services can be terminated at any point in time by the Android system to free up resources.

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pi);
```

[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service` in a proper way. When screen is turning off or device is locked, method `onPause` is called. Here you can start your service.

When the screen is unlocked, the app come in foreground again and it triggers `onResume`, where you can retrieve the data from your service and stop it. Then update the View with the data.

Don't try to update the View from the service while the app is on backgroud...  it will most probably crash and it is not optimal. Update it after app comes again in front.

Good luck!